# How do I limit CSS-formatting to a single element?

Tags: html, css

Im writing a bit of code tonight and I want my `h1` to align center. `h1 {text-align: center;}` but I don't want all my `h1` tags to be aligned. How do I write a Do Once statement in HTML? My coding experience is limited to cpp so this html stuff is a bit confusing ironically.

Comment: Use a class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class

Comment: add any class to `h1` and apply styling to that class only

Comment: Just assign an id to your H1 tag. So you can do: In HTML5: `<h1 id="myH1"></h1>`. In CSS: `h1#myH1 { text-align: center; }`.

Answer (score 4):

Make a class for this

```
<h1 class="text-center">My H1</h1>

.text-center {
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to style only one thing or part, I recommend you to use helper class.

**Helper class:**

The helper class is nothing but just the convention so that others could understand you. To do helper class the proper convention to write is adding `h` in front

For Example:
HTML:

```
 <h1 class="h-text-center">I am H1 </h1>
```

**Css: " ./helper.css " :**

```
   .h-text-center{
    text-align-center;
    
    }
```

**OR**

```
 .h-text-center{
    margin:0 auto;
    }
```

**OR**

```
justify-content:center; //in parent element

.h-text-center{

align-self:center;
}
```

**OR**

You can use the pseudo-element selector,
The`:first-child` selector is used to selecting the specified selector, only if it is the first child of its parent

```
div:first-child {
  text-align: center;
}

<div>
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h1>2</h1>
  <h1>3</h1>
  <h1>4</h1>
  <h1>5</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

to modify single h1 tag or any  you can use Inline css too. this is not really good practice but this will give you the result you asked.

check this

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center; color:red;">hi Buddy</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Working Code !!***

Using `:first-child` *(pseudo-class)* to align first `h1` tag center, but not remaining sibling `h1` tags.

```css
div > h1:first-child {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>hello1</h1>
  <h1>hello2</h1>
  <h1>hello3</h1>
  <h1>hello4</h1>
  <h1>hello5</h1>
</div>
```